# Long overflows : Fibonacci series

Tags: java, overflow

I'm trying to solve the second Euler problem (calculate sum of all even Fibonacci numbers < 4 million) and so far I've come up with this:

```
public class CCTrial1 {
    public static void fib(){
    long  a = 0, b = 1;
    long  c = 0, sum = 0;
    int i = 1;
    long even = 0;
    while(i < 400000){
        c = a + b;
        sum = c;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        if(sum %2 == 0){
            even += sum;

        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Count " +i);
    System.out.println("Last Fib no " +sum);
    System.out.println("Sum " +even);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        fib();
    }
 }
```

I have changed it to long and I still get an overflow. Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You seem to be calculating something like the first 400k fibonacci numbers, not just all under 4 million (which should be quite a few less)

Comment: Yes, sorry I had changed it to 400k but it doesn't even work for this.

Comment: i hate people saying "accept my answer", but i don't like asking a question and just doing nothing either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem involves Fibonacci terms less than 4 million, not the first 4 million Fibonacci terms.

For example, the 35th, 36th and 37th Fibonacci numbers are 5702887, 9227465 and 14930352; the problem statement excludes them all from consideration, because they are all greater than 4000000.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate all fibonacci numbers under 4 million, you shouldn't loop 4 million times. The 4 millionth fibonacci number is on the order of 10^835950 which is quite a bit outside of your range.

You should instead just plain do the while until a+b >= 4 million.

Answer (score 0):

Just print out all the numbers as you go through and see where the overflow occured. That way you'll see you can't get the first 4 million Fibonacci terms. You can get more Fibonacci information from [this link](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html).